# What does "pre-predicative" mean in the context of Husserl's Cartesian Meditations <52>?

Tags: phenomenology, husserl

In [Husserl's Cartesian Mediatations <52>](https://archive.org/details/CartesiamMeditations/page/n21/mode/2up)

The term **pre-predicative** is introduced in this way:

> Yet there is one more thing that should be brought out, to <52>
> supplement what we have said. We must distinguish the
> judgment in the broadest sense (something meant as being) and
> evidence in the broadest sense from pre-predicative judgment
> and from pre-predicative evidence respectively. Predicative includes pre-predicative evidence.

What does "pre-predicative" mean as in **"pre-predicative judgment"** and **"pre-predicative evidence"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the concluding sentence of your same reference:

> Consequently evidence of the ex-pression is also a determining part of the idea of scientific truth, as predicative complexes that are, or can be, grounded absolutely.

So Husserl seems to emphasize we need these pre-predicative judgements and evidences as a determining part to ground whole *idea* of scientific propositional truths. For example, in physics we have evidence to judge F=ma to be true under classical mechanics context, but we should not forget first of all we have some pre-predicative judgement and evidence regarding what's really force F, mass m and acceleration a. Otherwise we cannot ground Newton's second law absolutely.